# Plot colour coded contours as a parameter varies in a certain range

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

The following is a code for plotting the 0.1 contour of a complicated function $f(B,\zeta_1,\zeta_2,k_3,k_4,q)$ in the $B$-$\zeta_1$ plane, while keeping $\zeta_2$, $k_3$, $k_4$ and $q$ constant. Actually I need the $f=0$ contour but for that I need to have `PlotPoints` far more than 400, which is taking very long time to plot.

```
    q = 0.5; Subscript[\[Zeta], 2] = 0.5; Subscript[k, 3] = 1; 
    Subscript[k, 4] = -4.6; 
    ContourPlot[
       (1/Pi)*
           (180*
         ArcCos[(1 - (1/2)*
              Re[((1 + Conjugate[(-q^2)*(-1 + B + q^2) + 2*(1 + q^2)*
                                       Subscript[k, 3] + 
                      4*q^2*Subscript[\[Zeta], 1] + 
                      Sqrt[(1 - (-3 + B)*q^2 + q^4)^2 + 
                                         
                        8*q^2*(Subscript[\[Zeta], 
                        1]*(1 - (-2 + B)*q^2 + (1 + q^2)*Subscript[k, 3] + 
                                             
                        2*q^2*Subscript[\[Zeta], 1]) + (1 + q^2)*
                        Subscript[k, 4]*Subscript[\[Zeta], 2])]])*
                              
                  Subscript[\[Zeta], 2])/((1 + Conjugate[q]^2)*
                  Conjugate[Subscript[k, 4]]*
                              Subscript[\[Zeta], 1])])/(Sqrt[
              1 + Abs[Subscript[\[Zeta], 2]/Subscript[\[Zeta], 1]]^2]*
                     
             Sqrt[1 + (1/4)*
                Abs[(1/((1 + q^2)*Subscript[k, 4]))*(1 - 
                     q^2*(-1 + B + q^2) + 2*
                                      (1 + q^2)*Subscript[k, 3] + 
                     4*q^2*Subscript[\[Zeta], 1] + Sqrt[
                                      (1 - (-3 + B)*q^2 + q^4)^2 + 
                       8*q^2*(Subscript[\[Zeta], 1]*(1 - (-2 + B)*q^2 + 
                                             (1 + q^2)*Subscript[k, 3] + 
                        2*q^2*Subscript[\[Zeta], 1]) + (1 + q^2)*
                                            Subscript[k, 4]*
                        Subscript[\[Zeta], 2])])]^2 + 
                         (1/4)*
                Abs[(1/((1 + q^2)*Subscript[k, 4]))*(1 + q^4 + 
                     q^2*(3 - B + 
                                         4*Subscript[\[Zeta], 1]) + 
                     Sqrt[(1 - (-3 + B)*q^2 + q^4)^2 + 8*q^2*
                                          (Subscript[\[Zeta], 
                        1]*(1 - (-2 + B)*q^2 + (1 + q^2)*Subscript[k, 3] + 
                                             
                        2*q^2*Subscript[\[Zeta], 1]) + (1 + q^2)*
                        Subscript[k, 4]*Subscript[\[Zeta], 2])])]^
                             2])]) == 0.1, {B, 2, 
      25}, {Subscript[\[Zeta], 1], 0, 7}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
       PlotPoints -> 400, ContourStyle -> {Red}]
```

The plot obtained from this is shown as follows.

[image]

However, my main interest is plotting the colour coded $f=0$ contour in the $B$-$\zeta_1$ plane as $q$ varies between two given numbers, e.g., $q\in[0.1,0.7]$, while keeping $\zeta_2$, $k_3$ and $k_4$ fixed at the shown values.  I tried the `ConditionalExpression` function but it did not work. If someone could help me with this, it would be gratefully appreciated! Thanks. (Please note that I don't want the `Manipulate` environment.)

Comment: `ContourPlot3D`

Comment: @cvgmt, thanks! nice idea...but it would be great if a 2-dimensional representation of this can be obtained. that's why i seek a colour coded plot if possible.

Comment: Build multiple `CountourPlot`s, each with its own value of $q$, and then combine them with `Show` then? The size of the set of points where $f=0$ seems vanishingly small with the values you gave. Have you made separately certain that this set you are trying to plot actually exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Precision is an issue so avoid machine precision numbers.

```
Subscript[ζ, 2] = 1/2;
Subscript[k, 3] = 1;
Subscript[k, 4] = -23/5;

eqn = (1/Pi)*(180*
       ArcCos[(1 - (1/2)*
            Re[((1 + 
                  Conjugate[(-q^2)*(-1 + B + q^2) + 
                    2*(1 + q^2)*Subscript[k, 3] + 
                    4*q^2*Subscript[ζ, 1] + 
                    Sqrt[(1 - (-3 + B)*q^2 + q^4)^2 + 
                    8*q^2*(Subscript[ζ, 
                    1]*(1 - (-2 + B)*q^2 + (1 + q^2)*Subscript[k, 3] + 
                    2*q^2*Subscript[ζ, 1]) + (1 + q^2)*Subscript[k, 4]*
                    Subscript[ζ, 2])]])*
                Subscript[ζ, 2])/((1 + Conjugate[q]^2)*
                Conjugate[Subscript[k, 4]]*Subscript[ζ, 1])])/(Sqrt[
            1 + Abs[Subscript[ζ, 2]/Subscript[ζ, 1]]^2]*
           Sqrt[
            1 + (1/4)*
              Abs[(1/((1 + q^2)*Subscript[k, 4]))*(1 - q^2*(-1 + B + q^2) + 
                   2*(1 + q^2)*Subscript[k, 3] + 4*q^2*Subscript[ζ, 1] +
                    
                   Sqrt[(1 - (-3 + B)*q^2 + q^4)^2 + 
                    8*q^2*(Subscript[ζ, 
                    1]*(1 - (-2 + B)*q^2 + (1 + q^2)*Subscript[k, 3] + 
                    2*q^2*Subscript[ζ, 1]) + (1 + q^2)*Subscript[k, 4]*
                    Subscript[ζ, 2])])]^2 + (1/4)*
              Abs[(1/((1 + q^2)*Subscript[k, 4]))*(1 + q^4 + 
                   q^2*(3 - B + 4*Subscript[ζ, 1]) + 
                   Sqrt[(1 - (-3 + B)*q^2 + q^4)^2 + 
                    8*q^2*(Subscript[ζ, 
                    1]*(1 - (-2 + B)*q^2 + (1 + q^2)*Subscript[k, 3] + 
                    2*q^2*Subscript[ζ, 1]) + (1 + q^2)*Subscript[k, 4]*
                    Subscript[ζ, 2])])]^2])]) == 1/10 // Simplify;
```

After an initial plot, zoom in to the region of interest.

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate@
  Table[eqn, {q, 7/10, 1/4, -1/20}],
 {B, 19, 25}, {Subscript[ζ, 1], 2.3, 4.7},
 PlotLegends -> LineLegend[Range[0.7, 0.25, -0.05],
   LegendLabel -> Style[HoldForm[q], 14]],
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {B, Subscript[ζ, 1]}),
 PlotPoints -> 150,
 MaxRecursion -> 6,
 WorkingPrecision -> 25]
```

[image]

Note that for `q == 1/4` there are no results in this range of `{B, Subscript[ζ, 1]}`

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer!!